# Is init?(aDecoder:) or prepareForSegue(_:sender:) called first?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, uikit

**Intro**
I am trying to debug my program and I have come across a problem. I am getting the swift error: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.` This problem is from an implicitly unwrapped optional. The error is in ViewControllerB's `init?(aDecoder:)` and the place where I set the value is in ViewControllerA's `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` that uses a "show segue" to go to ViewControllerB.

**Problem**
This leads me to beleive that the `init?(aDecoder:)` method in ViewControllerB is called before the `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` in ViewControllerA. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  An object is always initialised before it can be used elsewhere in the application.

If there is work you need to do that depends upon the property being set, it's often appropriate to trigger that work from a `didSet` observer on the property or in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

Comment: To expand: "before it can be used elsewhere"… since the object is available via `segue.destinationViewController` the object is probably already initialized

Comment: Although I hesitate to agree with "always" since the object could technically be initialized lazily

Comment: The object will definitely be initialised.  Are you thinking of lazy properties?  That's not the initialisation of the object itself.  The object itself *has* to be initialised before it's available to `prepareForSegue()`.

Comment: That's true of the `UISegue` object passed in to the method, but the `UISegue`'s `destinationViewController` property could theoretically be loaded lazily. (But it's all semantics, because `UISegue` doesn't work that way.)

Comment: Sure, it *could* be loaded lazily.  But you're talking about property assignment, not object initialisation.  The object is *always* initialised first.

Comment: Right, but "before it can be used elsewhere in the application" could be *after* `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` is called if lazy stored properties were used.

Comment: `prepareForSegue()` *is* elsewhere in the application.  The initialiser always finishes running before the rest of the application can access the object.  Nowhere else in the application will have the opportunity to set a property on that object before the initialiser finishes running.